# How to set a time range by month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I can currently set a time range like so:

```
time_range = (24.hours.ago..Time.now)
```

How can I do this for start to end of months

examples:

```
time_range = (Feb.start..Feb.end)
time_range = (March.start..March.end)
time_range = (April.start..April.end)
```

Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to figure out the start of the month:

```
start_date = Date.new(2012,2,1)
```

for the end of the month:

```
end_date = start_date.end_of_month
```

finally

```
time_range = (start_date..end_date)
```